# Export everything within a namespace

Tags: typescript

I have a namespace, like so:

```js
export namespace A {
 const foo = "bar"
}
```

How can I export everything within that namespace in another namespace or module declaration (whichever works), like so:

```js
export namespace A {
 // export everything from other namespace at root level
 const bar = "foo"
}
```

I tried doing something like `export { A } from "./A"; export namespace A {}`, but that resulted in errors.